# How to migrate data (folders) from a server on a local private network to azure data lake?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, data-migration, azure-data-factory

I have a server located on a local secured network. I want to migrate the data periodically from this server to Azure data lake 2.0.

I tried using data factory, but was unsuccessful. Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried and what's the error message ? Please show us more details.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Data Factory should be fine for this, but you need to use a [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime). You would set up a linked service of type file system that uses the self-hosted IR as your source linked service. Then set up a linked service for ALDS Gen 2 to use for your destination. You can copy multiple files at once and preserve the folder hierarchy by making sure the copy behavior is set to PreserveHierarchy. You can find more information, including how to set your datasets and copy activity in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system#supported-capabilities).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful reply. I actually followed the same document you mentioned here. Le me clarify my scenario, I have a zipped folder which have several sub folders and each sub-folders have many files in it. Some files are binary files, some are csv and some are plain text. My requirement is to copy the zip folder as it is without unzipping it at the on-premise FTP sever. And this process is not one time but on a regular basis copy whenever a new zip files comes into FTP server.